# Getting highest column value from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a bit of trouble understanding all but the most basic joining concepts. The diagrams don't help much.

I've got three tables I want to join:

- environments,
- sessions, and
- logs

Here's some screenshots of the tables.

Environments:

[image: Environments]

Sessions:

[image: Sessions]

Logs:

[image: Logs]

I want to select columns environments.envCode and logs.type. What I want is to get the logs.type from the last log for each environment. Environments and logs are related through session by environments.envCode in sessions and sessions.sessionID in logs.

I've tried several ways of querying this but just can't seem to get it right. This is one of the ways I've tried to do it:

```
 SELECT environments.envCode
        ,logs.type 
        FROM environments
        LEFT JOIN session
        ON environments.envCode = session.envCode
        LEFT JOIN logs
        ON session.sessionID = logs.sessionID
        WHERE logs.logID = (SELECT MAX(logID) FROM logs);
```

What I'm getting now is one result, for only the row with the highest logID from logs. Makes sense, I understand why it's not giving me the results I'm looking for, but I'm still not sure how to go about getting the results I want.

Comment: You mentioned that you are having issues understanding basic Join concepts, so here's a [useful tutorial](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) that has proved helpful to me. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look now.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? I think the question is well written; we know the dbms, we see tables and data, we see some effort was made. So why does anybody downvote this? Well, +1 from me for compensation :-)

Comment: Cheers, and thanks for the solution :) I think sometimes when people see a novice question that has an easy solution for them they just downvote as it's a "dumb question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want only those result records where no later log entry EXISTS for the environment:

```
select 
  environments.envcode,
  logs.type 
from environments
left join session on environments.envcode = session.envcode
left join logs on session.sessionid = logs.sessionid
where not exists
(
  select *
  from sessions later_session
  join logs later_log on later_log.sessionid = later_session.sessionid
  where later_session.envcode = session.envcode
  and later_log.created > logs.created
);
```

EDIT: I changed above query so that the latest logs, not the latest sessions, get selected.

Comment: No, now I'm getting multiple results for each environment. I want to get *one* result for each of the environments, showing only the log type for the last added *log* (there's several logs per session and logID is auto incremental).

Comment: So how do you know what's the *latest* log? There is no log date, is there? Do you rely on logid order?

Comment: I am at this point, but it also has a created datetime column, so it's probably better to use that... Still doesn't solve the problem that I only want to select the latest log for each environment.

Comment: Simply join session and log to look for later log entries. I've changed the query accordingly.